# How to find specific data(field) in similar databases

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

We are using postgresql DB for our project. Each customer have their own database(all alike) i.e. We have common schemas for DB relations, for all these DBs.

I would like to search a particular field value among these DBs i.e. which particular database/databases contains that value. The problem I am facing is we have 15-20 databases(in normal situation), Now searching in each one of DB is not a good soln, So I am looking for some soln which can search in all the DB.

We can search through some script by using sqlalchemy, psycopg2 but my preference is if there is any other solution available.

Any type of help, suggestions, pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, there isn't much you can do besides actually searching in those 15-20 databases.

You could admittedly create an ugly view in yet another separate database, which queries those external databases using [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/dblink.html) (or the [Postgres foreign data wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html), when PG 9.3 ships). But that'll merely shift the burden of querying external databases downstream.

Another option, if changing your architecture somewhat is an option, is to use [DB schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-schemas.html) (one per customer) rather than completely separate databases. Perhaps with some [table inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-inherit.html) to query everything in one go from an admin schema that only you can access.

That being said, note that you'll end up querying from multiple sources in a way or another irrespective of what you actually do, short of merging the tables together and carrying a `customer_id` around.